# How to get google map's point?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

How do I get the return point into a variable to use with php?

I have

```
 function showAddress(address) {
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(
      address,
      function(point) {
        if (!point) {
          alert(address + " not found");
        } else {
        alert("Get point" +point);
        /*how to read point as php variable*/
          map.setCenter(point, 15);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Any info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var latLng = point.getLatLng();
var lat = latLng.lat();
var lon = latLng.lng();
```

`point` is a [GMarker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker), and you can get the 
[GLatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLng) using the `getLatLng()` function.

[Here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html)'s where I started for more info and examples

Comment: To pass a javascript variable to php, add the variable to a query string and then retrieve it using `$_GET`.  Something like `var p = "whatever"; location.href = "new_page.php?variable=" + p;`

Comment: @jason, tx for the $_get solution but i like to use a $_post solution. I have a form with a more variables. I tried to use hidden fields, but the vars aren't set. function(point) {
  if (!point) {
    alert(address + " not found");
  } else {
  
  lat = point.lat();
  lon = point.lng();
  $('#startPointLat').val(lat);
  $('#startPointLon').val(lon);

  alert("Get point" +lat  +"Get lon" +lon);
  /*how to read point as php variable*/
    map.setCenter(point, 15);
  }